# Refreshing datatable and using its features upon injecting the data into it using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, datatables

I'm trying to use data-tables features after the information have been injected into the table itself upon jquery post. The HTML markup for table is:

```
<table id="datatable-responsive" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="datatable-responsive_info" style="width: 100%;">
                <thead>
                    <tr role="row">
                        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-responsive" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 70px;" aria-label="First name: activate to sort column ascending">Store Name</th>
                        <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-responsive" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 268px;" aria-label="" aria-sort="ascending">Comment</th>
                        <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-responsive" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:18px;" aria-label="Last name: activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending">Your Rating</th>
                        <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-responsive" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 18px;" aria-label="Last name: activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending">Seller Feedback</th>
                        <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-responsive" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 18px;" aria-label="Last name: activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending">Delete</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
@if (ViewBag.Products != null)
{
                    foreach (var item in ViewBag.Products)
                    {
                        <tr role="row" class="odd">
                            <td class="" tabindex="0">@item.SaleNumber</td>
                            <td class="sorting_1">@item.SaleNumber</td>
                            <td class="sorting_1">@item.SaleNumber</td>
                            <td class="sorting_1">@item.SaleNumber</td>
                            <td class="sorting_1 deleteAction"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

The table is initially empty upon the page load... This is where I inject the data into the table when the post is done like following:

```
   var dbtb = $('<table />').append(data).find('#datatable-responsive').html();
                                   $('#datatable-responsive').html(dbtb);
```

But the table is completely unresponsive, I can't use any of its features, is there any way to let it know that I injected the data into it ??

Comment: Do you initialize the table after data injecting using $('#datatable-responsive').DataTable();
?

Comment: @KrzysztofKaźmierczak Yes that's what I've tried, but the datatable is still unresponsive. ..